# using nested case when and boolean in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use case when with boolean, getting syntax issue
cannot resolve "and" after second when, any suggestion what i am missing here?

```
df.withColumn("Keep_dropped")
   ,when((col("TARGET_ID")===col("SOURCE_ID"))
   .and(col("ingest_sr")===("COS")
   .and(col("timeinseconds")>(lastexectimeTS),
   true)
  .when((col("TARGET_ID")!=col("SOURCE_ID"))
   .and(col("ingest_sr").isNull
   .and(col("timeinseconds").isNull),true)
   .otherwise(false)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you take a look at the first condition of your second `when`, you're using `!=` which is a language operator, and returns a `Boolean`. and booleans do not have a method called `and`. you should use `!==` instead, which is an operator in spark API, like this:

```scala
df.withColumn("Keep_dropped")
   .when((col("TARGET_ID") === col("SOURCE_ID"))
   .and(col("ingest_sr") === ("COS")
   .and(col("timeinseconds") > (lastexectimeTS),
   true)
  .when((col("TARGET_ID") !== col("SOURCE_ID")) // note the !== here
   .and(col("ingest_sr").isNull
   .and(col("timeinseconds").isNull),true)
   .otherwise(false)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

And should be wrapped inside when like when(cond1.and(cond2)). Balance the parantheses. i believe should be like this.

```
df.withColumn("Keep_dropped"), when((functions.col("TARGET_ID")===functions.col("SOURCE_ID"))
                    .and(col("ingest_sr")===("COS"))
                    .and(col("timeinseconds")>(lastexectimeTS)), true)
```

Comment: That's what the OP is already doing, take a moment to count the parenthesis!

Comment: elaborated my answer, what i try to mean